# developing an application that display an image on a label(control) and after click that image the new image will display in other label (control)

Tags: c++, qt

i am working on **QT C++**,developing an application that display an image on a label(control) and after click that image the new image will display in other label (control). i create a new project:   **application->QtWidget Application**. then i select **class Qdialog**. in project file are
 - my_qlabel_mouseEvent.pro
and in header folder are 
 - dialog.h 
 - my_qlabel.h 
and then source folder has files 
1: dialog.cpp
2:main.cpp
3: my_qlabel.cpp

and then in form folder has 
1: dialog.cpp.

when i add the new **class my_qlabel** with **base class** **QLabel**, type information: **QWidget** after creating this the **setPixmap** does not work. its show error the error is that **"in constructor 'Dialog::Dialog(QWidget*)' class my_qlabel has no member named setPixmap**" please solve this error or reffer me any site or other sources.

```
**my_qlabel.cpp**

#include "my_qlabel.h"
#include <QPixmap>

my_qlabel::my_qlabel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{


}

void my_qlabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    emit Mouse_Pos();
}

void my_qlabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    emit Mouse_Pressed();
}

void my_qlabel::leaveEvent(QEvent *)
{
    emit Mouse_Left();
}



**main.cpp**

#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}


**dialog.cpp**

#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "my_qlabel.h"
#include <QPixmap>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QPixmap pix("E:/osld/andgate.png");

    ui->lblMouse->setPixmap(pix);

    connect(ui->lblMouse, SIGNAL(Mouse_Pressed()), this, SLOT(Mouse_Pressed()));
    connect(ui->lblMouse, SIGNAL(Mouse_Pos()), this, SLOT(Mouse_current_pos()));
    connect(ui->lblMouse, SIGNAL(Mouse_Left()), this, SLOT(Mouse_left()));


}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::Mouse_current_pos()
{
    ui->lblMouse_Current_Event->setText("Mouse Moving");

}

void Dialog::Mouse_Pressed()
{
    ui->lblMouse_Current_Event->setText("Mouse Pressed");

}

void Dialog::Mouse_left()
{
    ui->lblMouse_Current_Event->setText("Mouse Left");

}

**dialog.h**

#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private slots:

    void Mouse_current_pos();
    void Mouse_Pressed();
    void Mouse_left();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_H



**my_qlabel.h**

#ifndef MY_QLABEL_H
#define MY_QLABEL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPixmap>

class my_qlabel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit my_qlabel(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);
    void leaveEvent(QEvent *);

signals:
    void Mouse_Pressed();
    void Mouse_Pos();
    void Mouse_Left();

public slots:
};

#endif // MY_QLABEL_H
```

Comment: The baseclass of your `my_qlabel` is `QWidget`, not `QLabel` as you state in your question

Comment: then how to solve this??

Comment: Change the base class of my_qlabel. Question, do you know what inheritance is or did you simply copy code or have it automatically generated?